# What is the unit in date type series used in functions

Tags: excel, formula

I'm using the SLOPE Excel function on a date data type time series: 1 Jan, 1 Feb, 1 Mar and so on... I can't figure out the x axis time unit assumed in the resulting calculation so the number is quite useless to me.

Any hints?

Comment: As of Excel 2007, the slope function asks for known Y and X values. What quantities are you using in each one?

Comment: Hi, I'm using date types (eg: 01-01-2010, 01-02-2010...) for the x axis. I'd like to know in what scale is the result given; in other words y/T where T is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the answer to my question: in dates, the day is the integer part starting from 01-01-1900 while the decimal part represent the time (which timezone? ah, I don't think it's accounted for ;) )

Details here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214094